# Multiple authors with different primary affiliation, but same additional affiliation

Tags: footnotes, acm, affiliation, author, acmart

I am writing a paper with 2 authors that have different primary affiliations. However, they both have a common additional affiliation. Currently, this is what I do:

```
%%%% Proceedings format for most of ACM conferences (with the exceptions listed below) and all ICPS volumes.
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables

\setcopyright{rightsretained}

% DOI
\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
\acmConference[THIS '17]{Some ACM Conference}{July 2017}{Anywhere, USA} 
\acmYear{2017}
\copyrightyear{2017}

\acmPrice{15.00}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}

\author{Author One}
\additionalaffiliation{%
  \institution{Secondary Organization}
  \city{Commonville}
  \state{State}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My Company}
  \streetaddress{1234 Here Ave}
  \city{Location}
  \state{State}
  \postcode{12345}
}
\email{author_one@mycompany.com}

\author{Author Two}
\additionalaffiliation{%
  \institution{Secondary Organization}
  \city{Commonville}
  \state{State}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Other Company}
  \streetaddress{5678 There St}
  \city{Place} 
  \state{State} 
  \postcode{67890}
}
\email{author_two@othercompany.net}

%\author{Author Two\footnotemark[1]} % Next attempt: use this line instead of \author{Author Two} and \additionalaffiliation

\begin{abstract}
Here is my abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{this, that, another}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this creates two separate footnotes that say the exact same thing: "Also with Secondary Organization." Is there any way to just use one symbol next to both names so that they reference the same footnote?

I've also tried:

```
\author{Author Two\footnotemark[1]}
```

for the second author's name instead of using \additionalaffiliation again. This does produce the desired effect, but with a side effect too. Elsewhere in the document, when the authors are referenced, it outputs:

Author One, Author Two[1].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, please put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. In particular, what document class or package defines the macros that you are using?

Comment: I am using \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}. I didn't post the actual full document since it would be rather large and include work in progress that isn't ready to be made public yet.

Comment: So edit your question to make the document compilable.  You don't need to post the whole document, for this problem it doesn't even need to contain any main text.  Put the fragments in the `\documentclass{acmart} ... ` and add only the author code plus whatever else is necessary to make it compilable.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Ok - should be a compilable document now

Comment: May be you can fill a [bug report](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues).  Altough there are some closed bugs reports related [to multiple affiliations](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/98) and [more compact headers](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/329), your question looks valid and different than them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution. I've made a new command `\addauthornote` which takes a single argument, a number corresponding to the *n*-th additional affiliation. This will add the footnote mark corresponding to that additional affiliation and add it to the current author.

Here's a complete example using 4 authors with 2 additional affiliations.

```
%%%% Proceedings format for most of ACM conferences (with the exceptions listed below) and all ICPS volumes.
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\makeatletter

% Use this command to add an existing supplemental affiliation to an author
% \addauthornote{1} adds n-th additional affiliation mark.   
\newcommand\addauthornote[1]{%
  \if@ACM@anonymous\else
    \g@addto@macro\addresses{\@addauthornotemark{#1}}%
  \fi}

\newcommand\@addauthornotemark[1]{\let\@tmpcnta\c@footnote
   \setcounter{footnote}{#1}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
    \g@addto@macro\@currentauthors{\footnotemark\relax\let\c@footnote\@tmpcnta}}

\makeatother
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables

\setcopyright{rightsretained}

% DOI
\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
\acmConference[THIS '17]{Some ACM Conference}{July 2017}{Anywhere, USA} 
\acmYear{2017}
\copyrightyear{2017}

\acmPrice{15.00}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}

\author{Author One}
\additionalaffiliation{%
  \institution{Author 1 Secondary Organization}
  \city{Commonville}
  \state{State}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My Company}
  \streetaddress{1234 Here Ave}
  \city{Location}
  \state{State}
  \postcode{12345}
}
\email{author_one@mycompany.com}

\author{Author Two}
\additionalaffiliation{%
  \institution{Author 2 Secondary Organization}
  \city{Commonville}
  \state{State}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My Company}
  \streetaddress{1234 Here Ave}
  \city{Location}
  \state{State}
  \postcode{12345}
}
\email{author_two@mycompany.com}

\author{Author Three}
\addauthornote{2}

\affiliation{%
  \institution{Other Company}
  \streetaddress{5678 There St}
  \city{Place} 
  \state{State} 
  \postcode{67890}
}


\email{author_three@othercompany.net}

\author{Author Four}
\addauthornote{1}

\affiliation{%
  \institution{Other Company}
  \streetaddress{5678 There St}
  \city{Place} 
  \state{State} 
  \postcode{67890}
}


\email{author_four@othercompany.net}


\begin{abstract}
Here is my abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{this, that, another}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The only problem with your solution is the metadata generated by the template. The ACM template use the commands `\additionalaffiliation{}` and `\affiliation{}` to create author metadata that automated-tools can extract.  If you use your commands, or the official`\authornote` and `\authornotemark`, the corresponding metadata will be not generated.