# Show affiliation directly under author name

Tags: formatting, author, affiliation

I'm working on a paper with three authors, each with different affiliations. I want to list the authors such that their names are on one line and their affiliations are on another line just below it, lined up so that each affiliation is directly under the author name. Is there a way to accomplish this without manually spacing the affiliations? I've tried including a table in the author box but I get errors for using a table before the document begins.

As of now I have the affiliations in a footnote, and this is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%opening
\title{ This is a Paper }
\author{Author A\footnote{Affiliation A}, Author B\footnote{Affiliation B}, and Author C\footnote{Affiliation C}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

EDIT: There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381530/multiple-authors-with-different-primary-affiliation-but-same-additional-affilia?rq=1) in which one of the answers uses a custom function to display the affiliation directly under the author name, but the author names are scattered in a grid. If possible, I'd like to have the author names remain in a list like

> Author A, Author B, and Author C

with the affiliations directly under the author names.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381530/multiple-authors-with-different-primary-affiliation-but-same-additional-affilia?rq=1 It achieves the wanted effect

Comment: Thanks for the response! The link isn't actually super helpful; let me edit my question to clarify why not. Given how I worded my question the link would have been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use standard LaTeX syntax inside the argument of `\author`, i.e., use `\and` to separate the three author blocks. Then each block should be of the form

```
Author Name \\ Author Affiliation
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\title{ This is a Paper }
\author{Author A\\ \small Affiliation A % "\small" is optional
        \and 
        Author B\\ \small Affiliation B 
        \and 
        Author C\\ \small Affiliation C}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. I did edit the original question before I saw your answer, but simply adding a comma after authors A and B and the word "and" before author C achieved the desired effect. It looks a little clunky but it's what the editor wants.